# Instant notifications like Facebook

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am building a social application and was wondering how facebook achieve their notifications.
As you know, facebooks notifications are instant. As soon as someone takes an action, people are notified.

I assume they don't have a query running on the database all the time.

Can someone point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: The question is quite a bit open-ended as there's a ton of alternatives.
You'll need something to allow server to push to client.
[StackOverlow old question with info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471780/asp-net-http-server-push-to-client)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since your question is tagged with C#, ASP.NET you should use the awesome `SignalR` library. Basically `SignalR` enables you to send push notifications to the clients. Which exact underlying technique it uses is influenced by the capabilities of the Server and the Client.

There is a big real time chat site called jabbR that is built on top of `SignalR`:

http://jabbr.net/

Here are some more links that should get you started.

- Project site: http://signalr.net/
- Hosted Code (Open Source): https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR
- Wiki: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki
- Projects using it: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Projects-Using-SignalR

Answer (score 8):

Facebook uses a messaging protocol (which it designed) called [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/). This allows notifications from clients to servers with very low latency. I would imagine updates on the server would be triggered depending on the user action and relevant users that are logged in would be notified by the same mechanism.

Using a messaging protocol such as thrift (also see [Protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)) clients don't have to poll the server for updates, instead the server can push notifications to clients. To do this the server needs to have a notion of who is logged in at any one time (Login, logout handshaking) and of them, who should receive notifications from a particular client action.

Easier said than done, especially when you have 800 million potential users logged in!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at http://nodejs.org/ - it is an event-driven model which is perfectly ideal for a 'social network' / instant notifications scenario.

FYI: You also might find that using a non-SQL database such as MongoDB (http://www.mongodb.org/) will be a lot faster when querying from the DB since each 'person' object in a social network scenario has his/her own unique attributes - which in a normal SQL database is hard to design.